# 配列に配列を追加するベストプラクティス

Tags: javascript

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [5, 6, 7];
for (var x of b) {
    a.push(x);
}
// a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

配列に配列を追加する方法は他に `Array.prototype.push.apply` やライブラリを使用した方法などもあると思いますが、どの方法が一番良いと思いますか？
処理速度、メモリ使用量、書きやすさなど、メリットも含め教えてください。

また、スプレッド構文を使用した

```
a.push(...b);
```

という書き方もあるようですが、これは有効な方法なのでしょうか。

**2019/04/13 追記**
[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) を使用する、という回答を頂きましたが、これは「配列に他の配列や値をつないで**新しい配列を返す**」というもののようです。私が求めてるものはそうではなく、**既存の配列に要素を追加する**ものです。

```
a = a.concat(b)
```

と書けば結果は同じなのかも知れませんが、[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)  は新しい配列を生成しますので、配列のサイズが非常に大きい場合などに（一時的な）メモリ使用量の増加や、処理速度の面でデメリットがあるのではないかと感じています。そのようなことはないのでしょうか？

Comment: 書き方がいくつかある中で、何をもって「ベスト」とするのか(=何を優先したいのか)が提示されていないと、回答も定まらない気がします。

Comment: この質問にはいくつかの問題があるように見えます。 1. タイトルにある `配列に配列を追加する` ではなく、 `配列に配列の要素を追加する` のが目的である 2. @cubick 氏の指摘の通り、求めている尺度が不明瞭であり、何を求めているのか分からない（ > `どの方法が一番良いと思いますか？` という表現が顕著であるように思います） 3. スプレッド構文についての質問がおまけのようについていますが、これは別の質問として分けたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: 少なくとも私にとっては質問者さんが何を疑問に思っているのか明らかでしたので、それに答える回答をしました（それがSO的に“良い質問”であるかは別の観点でしょうが）。　スプレッド構文については`Array.prototype.push.apply`と一緒くたにできるであろうという観点からは余計なのかもしれませんが、（私の回答では重要度が低いので詳しい言及は避けたものの）独特のパフォーマンス傾向を示しており、結果論的ではありますがこの質問に含まれていることには意義があると感じます。

Comment: `配列に配列を追加する` で十分意味が通じると思うのですが。`配列に配列の要素を追加する` ですと、配列中の特定の要素を追加する意味合いが強くなり、かえって質問の意図から外れるように私には感じられます。厳密に言えば `配列に別配列の全要素を追加する` となるのかもしれませんが、それは冗長ではありませんか？そもそも、配列 a に 配列 b の内容がすべて追加されている `// a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` を例として書いているのですから、この点を誤解する理由が分かりません。

Comment: タイトルは質問のサマリーであるべきという観点からは、少々冗長であっても"ある配列に別の配列の全要素を追加する際のベストプラクティスは？"みたいな感じが良いと思いました。

Comment: よく言う言い方だと「配列と配列を結合する」あるいは「連結する」でしょうか。私は大きな問題だとは思いませんが、「追加する」だと複数の使われ方があるな、とは思いました（コードを見れば分かるのですが）。ただ、jirolaboさんが最初に思いついた言い方を残しておくことで他の方のググラビリティを確保することができるため、今回はこのままで良いのではなかろうかと思います。

Comment: > Array.prototype.concat は新しい配列を生成しますので、配列のサイズが非常に大きい場合などに（一時的な）メモリ使用量の増加や、処理速度の面でデメリットがあるのではないかと感じています。そのようなことはないのでしょうか？

この質問においては適当ではないかもしれませんが、 `a` への破壊的操作が許されない場合に `Array.prototype.concat` は妥当な選択肢だと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

結論からいえば、**場合によるがfor-of文とpushを使うのが無難**です。特に、配列への要素の追加を1回行うだけなら`concat`のほうが速い場合がありますが（Google Chromeで顕著）、要素の追加が何度も繰り返される場合、質問者さんが懸念する通り、`concat`を使うと配列オブジェクトが何度も作られるという点で不利になります。

---

まず、配列への要素の追加1回のパフォーマンスを比較してみます。この回答では4つの方法（`for-of`ループ、`Array.prototype.push.apply`、spread構文、そして`Array.prototype.concat`）を比較してみました。

まず[jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/)で[1000要素の場合](https://jsbench.me/p8jugdhw7t)と[100万要素の場合](https://jsbench.me/k3jugdq0rn)で速度を比較すると手元のPC（Win10 + **Google Chrome**）では以下の表のようになり、**concatが最速**という結果になりました。配列の要素として数値以外にも文字列やオブジェクトなどを試しましたが同じ傾向でした。また、**Edge**も同じ傾向でした。

```
|               | 1000 items    | 1000000 items |
| ------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| for-of        | 59,383 ops/s  | 17 ops/s      |
| push & apply  | 78,932 ops/s  | error         |
| push & spread | 19,079 ops/s  | error         |
| concat        | 104,070 ops/s | 40 ops/s      |
```

さらに、上記の表では100万要素の場合に`a.push.apply(a, b)`や`a.push(...b)`でエラーが発生しています。その理由は、これらの処理はあくまで「pushを100万個の引数で呼ぶ」という処理に相当するため、処理系が対応している引数の数の上限を超えているからです。この2つをこの目的で使用するのは（`b`の要素数が少なくてエラーが起きないと確信できない限りは）やめたほうがよいでしょう。

一方、**Firefox**では下記の結果になります。先程とは傾向がかなり異なり、**concatよりもfor-ofのほうが速い**です（それでもChromeの1/3以下の性能ですが）。

```
|               | 1000 items   | 1000000 items |
| ------------- | ------------ | ------------- |
| for-of        | 18,815 ops/s | 8 ops/s       |
| push & apply  | 3,750 ops/s  | error         |
| push & spread | 4,231 ops/s  | error         |
| concat        | 3,663 ops/s  | 5 ops/s       |
```

というわけで、`for-of`と`concat`の二択ではありますが一概にどちらがベストとは言いにくい結果となりました。

---

次に、テストケースを100要素の追加を1000回行うように変更してみます。この場合、`concat`では中間オブジェクトが多く作られるので不利になると予想されます。

[このテストケース](https://jsbench.me/wpjugfajuz)をGoogle Chromeで試してみたところ以下の結果となりました（Firefoxも同じ傾向）。

```
| for-of | 388 ops/s |
| concat | 4 ops/s   |
```

また、データは省略しますがconcatのほうがメモリ使用量が上がっており、これが実行速度にも悪影響を与えていると考えられます。

---

まとめると、`concat`はGoogle Chromeでは最も高速に動作しますが、何度も繰り返し使用する場合は新しいオブジェクトが何度も生成されることが原因で性能が大きく低下します。一方、`for-of`はそのような性能悪化が発生しない上、Firefoxでは最も高速です。このことから、`for-of`が最も無難ではないかと考えられます。

シチュエーションにもよりますが、配列への複数要素の追加があまり頻繁に起こらないならどちらでもよいでしょう。`concat`のほうが何をやっているのか分かりやすくてよいかもしれません。しかし、この操作が頻繁に行われる場合には`concat`を避けたほうがよいでしょう。